# Getting "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" error when trying to permanently delete group using MS Graph api

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to permanently delete group using MS Graph api. Method is implemented in C# with use of application permissions Group.ReadWrite.All according to documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.
Admin consent is granted. Method is following:

```
 [HttpDelete("permadelete/{azureId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PermadeleteGroupOrTeam(string azureId)
    {
        HttpContext.VerifyUserHasAnyAcceptedScope(adminScope);

        var tenantId = Request.HttpContext.User.GetTenantId();
        var dbClient = TCDBService.GetTenantDB(_dbSettings, tenantId);
        var _graphClient = GraphServiceClientFactory.GetGraphServiceClient(tenantId, new[] {"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }, _webOptions);

        try
        {
            await _graphClient.Directory.DeletedItems[azureId].Request().DeleteAsync();
            dbClient.DeleteGroupOrTeam(azureId);
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

When trying to run the method, I get the following error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2020-10-29T12:51:38",
        "request-id": "28fed12e-9338-4dee-b346-54ac66100b7f",
        "client-request-id": "28fed12e-9338-4dee-b346-54ac66100b7f"
    }
}
```

}

Graph call that is used is

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directory/deleteditems/id
```

When I try for example to perform this operation using Graph Explorer or in frontend using JavaScript and delegated permissions, it works as it should. But it is not what I am looking for because in this case there is no admin consent needed and user without Global admin role couldn't perform this action

Any idea what could be wrong or maybe someone have had the same issue?

Comment: please provide correlation id and timestamp of error message

Comment: edited error message

Comment: Please refer to this  [Github issue](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10515) and update you accordingly